# Adding link from node with jquery

Tags: jquery

New in jquery, want to store link data from server but it iss not working.

```js
var newImage = $('<td id="tdimage"> <img src='+data.image+' widht=\'100\' height =\'100\'> </td>');
        var newName = $('<td id="tdname">' + data.name + '</td>');
        var newDesc = $('<td id="tddesc">' + data.description + '</td>');
        var newPieces = $('<td id="tdpieces">' + data.pieces + '</td>');
        var newLinks = $('<td id="tdlinks"> <a href=\"' + data.links +'\"> </a></td>');
var row = $('<tr>').append(newImage).append(newName).append(newDesc).append(newPieces).append(newLinks).append(btns);

row.data('id', data._id);
        row.data('name', data.name);
        row.data('pieces', data.pieces);
        row.data('desc', data.description);
        row.data('links', data.links);
        $('.table_body').append(row);
```

Comment: Please explain more about your problem, what is expected behavior and current one.

Comment: i want to create a dynamic anchor tag in a form with jqurey which will have the href value from the database , i also did for the image , image works fine but anchor is not working and sorry for my poor english

Comment: how you are appending anchor tag to your html?

Comment: can you please add your html code and put some more explaination like where you want to add the link and anchor tags

Comment: edited  can you kindly check above